# Browser sends NTLM ticket instead of Kerberos ticket

Tags: apache, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, ntlm

I'm having a problem that's driving me nuts. I'm trying to achive single sign-on on a combination of windows server 2012 as active directory server, ubuntu 12.04 with apache as webserver and a windows 7 laptop as client (all 3 on the same local network). I think I've set up everything correct:

- I've made a keytab file on the AD-server and when using this from the kinit command on the webserver I get no errors and I can confirm that the kerberos ticket is received using the klist afterwards.
- I've setup the AD-realm in the krb5.conf file on the webserver and since kinit works I asume that this is done correctly.
- The protected directory I'm testing on is setup in apache2.conf as follows:
  AuthType Kerberos
  KrbMethodNegotiate On
  KrbMethodK5Passwd On
  KrbAuthRealms ADREALM.LOCAL
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/apache2/test.keytab
  KrbServiceName NameOfSPNInKeyTabFile
  Require valid-user
- The laptop has been added to the AD-server and after logging on to it there are 3 KerbTickets listed when executing klist.
- I've added the ip-address of the webserver to the list of trusted sites in IE 11 (both http and https).

Still, when I try to access the protected site on the webserver I keep getting a box asking for login and password. When I type these in I get authenticated and get access to the site.

Using WireShark I can se that the client first sends an NTLM ticket when asked for authentication. Since the webserver expects a kerberos-ticket this fails and the browser fall-back to simple authentication asking for login and password. When these are received, the webserver contacts the AD-server and verifies the credentials. So the authentication works - it's just single sign-on that fails.

So the big question is: Why is the browser sending an NTLM-ticket in this situation? I've tested this with both ie, firefox and chrome and they all return an NTLM-ticket. I've tried different combinations of SPN-names, but all with the same result. Are there some naming conventions I've missed or what else could be wrong?

Comment: May not be at all related to this problem but in a multi-forest environment, don't forget about KFSO. I've written up my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36625744/594137).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the DNS was the problem. I added the webserver to the DNS on the AD-Server  and afterwards the kerberos ticket was transferred when opening the page from the laptop.

Comment: Bjarke, can you please mention what exact steps you did? We are facing similar issue.
Sometimes we get kerberos token, while most of the times, it is NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but with the cooperation of our AD admins. They never made it actually clear what black magic was required on the AD side, but there is some kind of 'domain trust' required. This trust was to allow the web client to send 
GSSAPI credentials first. It took us several weeks to figure this out.

The one difference between our config and yours was

KrbMethodK5Passwd Off

You should also be aware that for Windows clients outside your AD structure, getting this to work is next to impossible. I use a mod_rewrite to direct them to the form based login if they have an external ip address. A similar redirect is used for the clients that fail the initial GSSAPI version.

You might find some additional hints on this web page.

https://weblogin.stanford.edu/config.html

Comment: Just to be sure - the domain trust has to be between the webserver (apache) and the AD-server? Any idea how to make this trust?

Comment: Yes there is some magic config on the AD server side that will force the client to send GSSAPI first rather than NTLM. I've no idea what it is. Maybe some magic config on the SPN for the apache server?