# WWW-Authenticate uses NTLM and not Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, www-authenticate

I'm running a NodeJS server on a Windows Server 2008.

The server doesn't do much but I set the header for 401, WWW-Authenticate Negotiation which I know can go either with his default Kerberos authentication or if it's not available then with NTLM.

I downloaded fiddler and discovered that when I try to reach the server it tries to authenticate with NTLM(prompt me for username and password) rather than Kerberos, even though the computer is in the same domain as the server and when I do run the command "klist" it does show me that he has tokens which means that he already authenticated with Kerberos(doesn't it?).

My question is how can I make it authenticate with Kerberos rather than NTLM - why does he go to NTLM in the first place?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is SPN registered for the server?

Comment: I think it is, but I didn't really get how am I suppose to do it. I mean I did spnset but after I did that, what am I suppose to do? I'm not even sure I did it right to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You client is probably unable to obtain a server ticket for that machine. Use Wireshark and check for Kerberos `TGS-REQ` messages. Please search SO for my similar answers, I was already able to help in such situations.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything related to Kerberos TGS-REQ. It just does 401 Unauthorized then NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE.

Comment: Who does NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to read up on Kerberos.  You probably have a TGT (ticket granting ticket) , which proves you authenticated to AD (KDC).  You still need a ST (service ticket) for the specific service/server instanced.  http/servername.  For this to work, you need an SPN registered for the service.  the SPN must be registered to the account that will be decrytping the ST.

Fiddler showing that you don't send a ST shows that you didn't get one.  You likely will need a sniffer, not just Fiddler.  You will see, on port 88, your workstation try to request the ST from a KDC, then fail, then fall back to NTLM.  You want to see the ST req get back a ST.

this is a great starter, despite being from 2000  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742431.aspx

For more meaningful assistance, I'd need to see your app URL, your SPN info via setspn -l , and server hostname.

Comment: Im surfing to the app with an ip address "10.0.0.19:3000" is that even good? and I registered an SPN like this "setspn -s HTTP/kerb.name.com:3000 kerb". this what setspn -l gives : "Registered ServicePrinicpalNames for CN=the serv, CN=Computers,DC=name,DC=com: http/kerb.name.com" and DC: \\WIN-7II7OV492KP.name.com . Is that enough information?

Comment: the SPN needs to align with the FQDN section of your URL, as you use it in the browser. you may want to do a setspn -s HTTP/10.0.0.19:3000 kerb as well.  is the account kerb acutaly running your web server?  does this run on top of IIS?   If you set the spn correctly, you will at least get it from the KDC.  If you fail after that, then you know there is an issue with the identity your web server is running under.

Comment: Yes the account kerb is the one running the server.I will download sniffer also and try to set the SPN better and see what it does. I will tell you after. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did not notice that you asked if it is running on IIS. Currently it is but I would like it to run on a linux machine. Is there something different I am suppose to do?

Comment: oh, linux.  I see a few nodeJS kerb packages.  You'll just need to follow their instructions to set the service account and password, or create the keytab.

Answer (score 0):

As this hasn't been marked as fixed I thought I would add a solution which worked for me. YMMV as in my environment we have multiple forests with trust relationships.

In my case, the user running the browser (and therefore making the HTTP GET) was in DOMA, but the web server was joined to DOMB. When the client tried to find the SPN of `HTTP/webserver.domainb.example.com`, it was looking for it in the DOMA.

I *wrongly* assumed that because a bi-directional trust relationship existed between DOMA and DOMB that it would figure out to look in DOMB and do so. Unfortunately it does not and you must [Configure Kerberos Forest Search Order](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/configure-kerberos-forest-search-order-kfso(v=ws.10).aspx). This may be done per client (Computer Configuration → Policies → Administrative Templates → System → Kerberos → Use forest search order) on Windows 7, or per KDC (Computer Configuration → Policies → Administrative Templates → System → KDC → Use forest search order) on Windows Server 2008R2.

*Note: [Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24756858/594137)'s advice to use Wireshark and look for TGS-REQ messages was what led me to finding the KFSO setting so many thanks to him.*