# WWW-Authenticate not working with Kerberos (only NTLM)

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, ntlm

I'm having a problem to setup SSO for the intranet websites. Currently i'm working with Tomcat 8.0 and [Waffle 1.8.4](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle). They work great, but there is only 1 problem: the browsers (Firefox and IE after the settings were applied as described [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520668)  and  [here](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM)) can not do Kerberos authentication, only NTLM.

I analyzed the traffic with Wireshark, Tomcat sends the `http` header field "WWW-Authenticate" and the browser answers a base64-encoded string in the header field "Authentication", that contains NTLMSSP. I guess this is not Kerberos, or is it ?

I read a post ([WWW-Authenticate uses NTLM and not Kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756677/www-authenticate-uses-ntlm-and-not-kerberos?noredirect=1&lq=1)), that for Kerberos to work, the server has to be registered in the AD with the command setspn.exe.
I try to get the right syntax for setspn ([described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2017)), but without any luck.
The server has the following parameters:

- **IP: 10.0.0.1**
- **Service: Tomcat-Http**
- **Port: 8080**
- **Accountname: company-net\foobar**

I use this command for setspn:

```
setspn -A "HTTP/10.0.0.1:8080 company-net\foobar"
```

but not works. Both the server and the client are in the same Windows domain, using Windows 10.

What is wrong with it?

Do i need anything else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerberos relies on DNS (valid hostnames) and SPNs to function. Looks like you've done a bit of research so far which is good.  What isn't that well known is that when you point an otherwise perfectly working fine Kerberos client to the IP of a host, rather than to it's DNS hostname, Kerberos will be bypassed and the fallback authentication mechanism will be employed instead - NTLM in this case.

Michael-O, the top Kerberos contributor to this forum, [said it best with his answer about this back in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260587/kerberos-fails-when-accessing-site-by-ip-address):

> Kerberos does not work with IP adresses, it relies on domain names and
>   correct DNS entries only.

Comment: Exactly this. IP addresses aren't supported. EXCEPT they are now, in Win 10 1507+ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/whats-new-in-kerberos-authentication

Comment: Thank you for the help. Figuring out, that IP address isn't allowed, would have cost me a lot of time.
I'm just reading about, that Windows 10 disabled the registry key

    allowtgtsessionkey

([1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/308339/registry-key-to-allow-session-keys-to-be-sent-in-kerberos-ticket-grant), [2](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6722928)), so we have to use the Windows SSPI API (Waffle, [Nsspi](https://github.com/antiduh/nsspi) use C# to access to the security context) and can forget a pure Java solution, like JGSS, JAAS, or SPNEGO.
Did you noticed this?